# pull-back of the tautological 1-form to a section

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, symplectic-geometry

- Suppose $M$ is a differentiable manifold of dimension $m < \infty$.
- Let $T^*M$ be its cotangent bundle. Let $\alpha \in T^*T^*M$ be the tautological $1$-form given by $\alpha_{(p, \lambda)}(\xi) := \lambda(D\pi(p, \lambda)\xi)$ where $\pi(p, \lambda):= p$ is the projection $T^*M\rightarrow M$ and therefore $D\pi(p, \lambda): T_{(p, \lambda)}T^*M\rightarrow T_pM$.
- Let $\omega := -\mathrm{d}\alpha$ the symplectic 2-form associated to it. Let $\mu$ be a closed $1$-form on $M$. (In fancy notation $\mu \in \Lambda^1(T^*M) = \Gamma(T^*M)$.)

There is this classical fact that if $\iota:\mu(M)\rightarrow T^*M$ be the inclusion, then $\iota^*\omega = 0$ and therefore, $\mu(M)$ is a Lagrangian submanifold of $T^*M$. Now for some reason I have trouble to show this. Could you help me to complete my attempt? (I don't want to identify objects that do not belong to the same set in my proof.)

---

***Attempt***:

Firstly, $\iota^*\omega = \iota^* (-\mathrm{d}\alpha) = -\mathrm{d}(\iota^*\alpha)$. It is therefore enough to show that $\mathrm{d}(\iota^*\alpha) = 0$. Let $\underset{\theta}{\underbrace{\left.\iota\right|_{\mu(M)}}}:= \iota^*\alpha$. Then for $(p, \lambda) \in T^*M$ (i.e. $p \in M$ and $\lambda \in T_p^*M$):
\begin{align*}
(\mathrm{d}\theta)_{(p, \lambda)}(v_1, v_2)
&=
\theta_{(p, \lambda)}(v_2) - \theta_{(p, \lambda)}(v_1) - \theta_{(p, \lambda)}([v_1, v_2]) \\
&=
\iota_{(p, \lambda)}(D\iota(p, \lambda)v_2) - \iota_{(p, \lambda)}(D\iota(p, \lambda)v_1) - \iota_{(p, \lambda)}(D\iota(p, \lambda)[v_1, v_2]).
\end{align*}

I am stuck here. I think I have to somehow invlove $\mathrm{d}\mu = 0$ into my computations. (The classic argument says that the pull back of the tautological $1$-form is $\mu$ and the rest is therefore obvious. I'm exactly unsure of how to show the first part of this argument.) Thanks again for your help in advance.

Comment: For starters, your fancy notation is wrong. A $1$-form is a section of $T^*M$, not of $TM$. Your formula for $d\theta(v_1,v_2)$ is also wrong. What is $\theta$?

Comment: Yes. It was meant $T^*M$. The $1$-form $\theta$ is defined to be the pullback of $\alpha$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I wrote something as my answer. This is what I understood from a proof that I read but I'm still confused about something. Doesn't a manifold being Lagrangian mean that the pull back of the symplectic form under the inclusion is $0$? The pull-back in my answer pulls back the symplectic form to some differential form above $M$ not $s_\lambda(M)$!

Comment: $s_\lambda$ maps $M$ diffeomorphically to $s_\lambda(M)$. The restriction of a form to the image is $0$ if and only if its pullback to $M$ (by the section) is $0$.

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot. Actually before reading this I went to discuss this with a friend of mine and he told me the same thing that you wrote. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes local coordinates make the formalism clearer. In the standard "physicists' notation," let $(q,p)$ be the usual local coordinates on $T^*M$. Then $\alpha = p\,dq = \sum p_i dq^i$. If $\mu = \sum f_i\,dq^i = f\,dq$, then $s_\mu(q)=(q,f(q))$, and so $s_\mu^*\alpha = f\,dq = \mu$, and so $d(s_\mu^*\alpha)=d\mu = 0$. (Indeed, $\alpha$ is called the tautological $1$-form because $s_\mu^*\alpha = \mu$. Note, also, that since $s_\mu$ is a diffeomorphism to its image, it is natural to think of $\iota$ precisely as $s_\mu$, with domain $M$.)

Comment: In local coordinates, why is it easy to see $s_\mu^*\alpha = \mu$?

Comment: I wrote it for you. :) $s_\mu(q)=(q,f(q))$, so $p=f(q)$. Therefore, $s_\mu^*\alpha = f(q)\,dq = \mu$ (by definition).

Comment: I get confused. Why replacing $f(q)$ by $p$ means pulling back? I agree that the local chart proofs in countless situations make life so much easier but I always get confused what are the tricks that make people work with them so easily. I'm always get lost . That's why I always do these horrible long proofs because I'm uncertain of how to do things otherwise and not do a mistake. If someone could help me realise how to do computations in charts I would owe them a lot.

Comment: No, we're setting $p=f(q)$. Think about the graph of a function $y=f(x)$. It's the set of points $(x,y)$ with $y=f(x)$. Our section is locally just this. It's the graph of the function $p=f(q)$.

Comment: Hi. I just came back after all this time and your answer is as clear as light to me. Sorry I didn't understand before! $S_\mu^* (p_i \mathrm{d}q_i) = (S_\mu^* pr_i) \mathrm{d}(S_\mu^* \mathrm{pr}_{i + n}) = \mathrm{pr}_i \mathrm{d}(\mathrm{pr}_{i + n} \circ S_\mu) = q_i \mathrm{d}f_i$. Therefore $S_\mu^* p\mathrm{d}q = q\mathrm{d}f$.

Comment: A similar argument shows if $(y_1, ..., y_n) = f(x_1, ..., x_n)$ and $I = (i_1, ..., i_k)$ is a multi-index, the pull back of $\mathrm{d}y_{i_1} \wedge ... \wedge dy_{i_k}$ is nothing but $\mathrm{d}f_{i_1} \wedge ... \wedge \mathrm{d}f_{i_k}$. The benifit to this in practice is that we can expand each $df_{i_m}$ in terms of $x$ as $\sum_{j = 1}^n(\partial_{x_j}f_{i_m})\mathrm{d}x_j$. In general a symplectic form in the $y$-space is a sum $\varphi_I dy_I$. The pull back of $\varphi_I$ is $\varphi\circ f$ and we know how to pull back $dy_I$. So, formal easy computations give the correct answer.

Comment: Now that you’re finally convinced, you should accept an answer so that the question does not remain on the unanswered list.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me ^^. I just did. Thanks again for your answer as well.

Comment: Also in my comment above by symplectic form I meant a differential form!

Answer (score 0):

I just realized what is going on. I read a proof but it seems a little bit strange to me why everything just works perfectly. (Maybe because that is the right way to write everything clearly? Anyways, below I try to explain Da Silva's proof.)

---

Just to be clear, we consider a difference between $\displaystyle\bigsqcup_{x \in M} T_x^*M$ and $\displaystyle\bigcup_{x \in M} T_x^*M$ and what we consider as the tangent bundle is the second one. Then

$$
  T^*M = \bigsqcup_{x \in M} T_x^*M := \bigcup_{x \in M} \Big(\{x\} \times T_x^*M\Big) \subseteq M\times \bigcup_{x \in M} T_x^*M
$$
and
\begin{align*}
  \lambda:M\longrightarrow &\bigcup_{x \in M} T_x^*M; \quad x \mapsto \lambda(x)
  \\[2ex]
  \lambda_\mu: M \longrightarrow &T^*M; \quad x \mapsto (x, \lambda(x)).
\end{align*}

We also recall that if $L:V\rightarrow W$ is a linear map, then $L^*:W^* \rightarrow V^*$ is another linear map associated to it given by $L^*(\lambda):= \lambda \circ L$ which completes the following diagram:

With these out of the way, we can do the following series of computation:

\begin{align*}
  (s_\lambda^* \alpha)(x)
  &=
  \alpha_{s_\lambda(x)} \circ Ds_\lambda(x)
  \tag{definition of pull back}
  \\
  &=
  (Ds_\lambda(x))^*\alpha_{s_\lambda(x)}
  \\
  &=
  (DS_\lambda(x))^*D\pi(S_\lambda(x))^*(\lambda(x))
  \tag{definition of $\alpha$}
  \\
  &=
  (D\pi(S_\lambda(x)\circ DS_\lambda(x))^*(\lambda(x))
  \\
  &=
  (D(\pi\circ S_\lambda)(x))^*\mu(x) = (\mathrm{id})^*\lambda(x) = \lambda(x).
\end{align*}

This shows that $s_\lambda^* \alpha = \lambda$. Therefore

\begin{align*}
  s_\lambda^* \omega
  &=
  s_\lambda^* (-\mathrm{d}\alpha)
  \\
  &=
  -\mathrm{d}(s_\lambda^*{\alpha})
  \\
  &=
  -\mathrm{d}\lambda
  \\
  &=
  0.
\end{align*}